# ERROR 1: Input values and/or interval settings would lead to too many levels

Tags: qgis, error, contour

I get the following error when generating contours from a LiDAR generated DEM.  I have completed this task in the past with no errors and all of a sudden, I now get this error:

> ERROR 1: Input values and/or interval settings would lead to too many levels Process returned error code 1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Chose a wider gap?

Comment: I have done this several times the exact same way using the same LiDAR data source with no issues.  I have tried changing all inputs variable with no different results.  Even started completely over multiple times.

Comment: If you've already done this with this data why are you doing it again? Something must have changed to get a different result

Comment: Can you give more information to the steps you take to make the contours?